# Publish .NET 7 Blazor to Linux doesn't have styles sheets

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I am not sure where the component CSS files get put.  I created the publish directory with VS2020 on Windows.

I had an ItemGroup to get it to copy the wwwroot folder.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="wwwroot\**">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

None of my component CSS is getting published.  It works fine on Windows.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Windows what, Linux what?  Windows dev computer, Apache server?  CSS files are just in wwwroot, and there's nothing stopping you from copying them into your app's folder on your live server.

Comment: Also, it could be possible that the files were once copied to the window machine manually or because of a setting which is changed ever since it was first copied. This might result in the files already being available in the windows machine. Please provide more information about your environment.